# How to Handle 500 error Page in Sitecore Headless

Tags: jss, nextjs, sxa-jss

I have created a custom `500.tsx` page under the `pages` folder. But still, I am unable to get my 500 page working, instead, it shows the default error message.

[image]

I have tried deleting my custom 500 pages so that Nextjs `_error.tsx` works, but the behavior is still the same, it shows the default error message.

am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Next.js apps support custom error pages. The JSS Next.js sample app includes custom error page implementations for errors with the status codes 404 and 500.

The sample JSS Next.js app provides a custom 500 page, defined in the file `src/pages/_error.tsx`.

Next.js handles 500 errors client-side and server-side. The 500 error page is rendered for all errors except 404 in `production`. In development, the application renders the error with the call stack.

Try to run an application in `production mode`. You can check the `package.json` for the command `next build`.

Refer to the below links for more details.

- [Nextjs commands to run an application in development/production mode](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/installation)
- [Error pages in the JSS Next.js sample app](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/21/sitecore-headless-development/error-pages-in-the-jss-next-js-sample-app.html)
- [_error.tsx code from BasicCompany example](https://github.com/Sitecore/Helix.Examples/blob/master/examples/helix-basic-nextjs/src/Project/BasicCompany/nextjs/src/pages/_error.tsx)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sumit, Thanks for the answer all things are in place I have already followed the steps that are mentioned in your answer, but still the same issue